# How can I create a custom type / typedef in C# to keep from incorrectly assigning values?

Tags: c#

I'm a C/C++ guy with a growing confidence in C#, but have run into a blocker that I can't seem to find the right search word/phrase.  I am looking through an existing codeset which uses a "float" type to manipulate/pass data around.  The problem with this is that the data in question can be expressed in different units, and some of the routines expect one unit, while others, the second unit is used.  This is making it extremely difficult to read/follow/debug.  A familiar example may be with units of measurement.  Let's say for example it's weight.  So, it's a mix of using ounces & pounds (or grams & kg.) So, I want to change the local variables and the routine definitions to use/take in a "PoundsType" or "OuncesType" - so, when I see it in the code it's clear what unit the number should be in.  I would like to use it just like I would a "float", (without the "new" or getting the value instead of indexing into a class) but let the compiler complain if the wrong unit is used somewhere.  (Similar to how an enum would work)
I saw through the googles someone suggested "using PoundsType = float;" but before I could test to see if that would meet my needs, that line wouldn't even compile.  - So, I don't know if it's been taken out of the language, or was never valid.
An example of what I'm after would be:

```
void foo (PoundsType valueInPounds) { /* do something. */ }
void bar (OuncesType valueInOunces) {/* do something. */ }
PoundsType ouncesToPounds (OuncesType NumOunces) {return NumOunces / 16.0F; }
main () 
{
PoundsType numPounds = 50;
OuncesType numOunces = 38;
bar (numPounds); /* compile error */
}
```

Comment: _"that line wouldn't even compile"_ -- the syntax you were given is wrong. You would need to use `using PoundsType = System.Single;`. The `float` keyword is an _alias_ for the `System.Single` type, and isn't supported in the `using` directive syntax that creates (yet another) alias for the type. See duplicate for other `typedef`-related options in C#.

Comment: Side note: if you really need units of measurement working without major pain... consider alternative languages - if you want to stay with .Net F# is an option -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/units-of-measure

Comment: You can define a bunch of structs, with operator overloads.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, that was my first instinct, unfortunately C# doesn't allow operator overload for the "=" operator.  Peter's correction compiles, unfortunately it doesn't provide the type safety was after... FOLLOW UP: So, the language docs say C# doesn't allow operator overload of "=", but you can do it in an roundabout way via a "static implicit operator OuncesType (float x)" -- and then it allows for OuncesType oz = 32F; I found the first steps in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925361/is-there-a-way-to-define-c-sharp-strongly-typed-aliases-of-existing-primitive-ty

Comment: Yeah, implicit casting is how you change how "=" constructs or deconstructs types.